# Simple Javascript Countdown how to update global from setintervals local function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am pulling countdown data(just a number like 10,15..) from db and making it equal to global.
just under class.

```
countdown:any;
```

---

```
 console.log(this.countdown);//i got data 10 sec
let downloadTimer=setInterval(function counter(countdown){
    countdown--;        // how to update this.countdown ?
console.log(countdown);
    if(countdown <= 0){
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        console.log("time is up!");
      }
    },1000,this.countdown);
```

I am starting with sending this.countdown to counter parameter but then how do i update this.countdown from local counter function? because when setinterval iterates it always calls this.countdown so counter stucks at first this.countdown value.

If i do it without parameter i cant access this.counter from counter local function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass a single scalar value, `this.countdown`, which is does, but you can't update that the same way you can an object or array and get the side effect of updating the original.

You could pass a reference to `this` and then use it to update the original:

```js
class test {
  constructor() {
    this.countdown = 20
  }
  doit() {
    console.log(this.countdown); //i got data 10 sec
    let downloadTimer = setInterval(function counter(obj) {
      obj.countdown--; // how to update this.countdown ?
      console.log(obj.countdown);
      if (obj.countdown <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        console.log("time is up!");
      }
    }, 200, this);

  }
}

var t = new test
t.doit()
```

You could also use an arrow function to capture the value of `this` rather than passing it in:

```js
class test {
  constructor() {
    this.countdown = 20
  }
  doit() {
    console.log(this.countdown); //i got data 10 sec
    let downloadTimer = setInterval(() => {
      this.countdown--; // how to update this.countdown ?
      console.log(this.countdown);
      if (this.countdown <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        console.log("time is up!");
      }
    }, 200);

  }
}

var t = new test
t.doit()
```